# How to remove SessionID when signout the site in mvc 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

My problem is sessionid,when i create sessionid,it is creating,when i signout the site it want expire my sessionid but it is not expiring,again it is giving same sessionid,i am giving my code below,please help me some one.

```
session["value"]=sessionid; //it is varible name;     


Public ActionResult Logout()
{
    session.remove("value");
   retun view();
}
```

thank for Advance,
gowtham g.

Answer (score 0):

To be double sure, always do the following:

```
Public ActionResult Logout()
{
session.remove("value");

session["value"] = null;

retun view();
}
```

Assigning `null` or `""` to it works all the time.

You can use all these methods:
The Abandon method should work:

```
Session.Abandon();
```

If you want to remove a specific item from the session use :

```
Session.Remove("YourItem");
```

If you just want to clear a value you can do:

```
Session["YourItem"] = null;
```

If you want to clear all keys do:

```
Session.Clear();
```

Comment: The above will add the key back in with a null value which is unlikely to be what the OP requires.

Comment: Thanks for reply sir,session value is passing Logout also,session null also showing session value.

Comment: @Gowthamg: 'session null also showing session value', meaning?

Comment: In logout action,session["value"]=null,showing session id value after logout also,it is not showing null value sir.

Comment: @Gowthamg: only possibility i can guess is, it must be getting reassigned somewhere.

Comment: Or that you are setting the session id variable before removing it from the session? Ideally need some more code where you are displaying it. Maybe instead of returing the view do "return RedirectToAction("Index");" where Index is a another valid Action in the controller. Do you get the same issue when trying to retrieve the session id from the other action?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the below if you want to end the session.

```
Session.Abandon();
```

Or you can call the below to remove all keys and values for a given session.

```
 Session.Clear();
```

Handling authentication and authorisation manually (which looks like you're trying to do) is error prone and risky. Have you considered using a framework such as ASP.NET Identity?

http://www.asp.net/identity

After hearing your comments it sounds like something else is going on. Maybe check in the global.asax to see if anything is being set there.

Often the best way of fixing an issue is to deomostrate it in as little code as possible, then keep adding functionality until you hit an issue.

If you create a new MVC project and add the following actions to the home controller this code will demonstrate that the

```
Session.Abandon();
```

Works as it should.

I suggest you use the following code in your problem controller, just have a link to the Logout action on the Index view. By setting up break points and stepping through the code you will see that it works.

If you still have an issue then it must be caused somwhere else in your code and you should create a fresh MVC project. Get my example working then add code from your project until it breaks.

Controller code.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var value = Session["value"];
    Session["value"] = "foo";
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Logout()
{

    var value = Session["value"];

    Session.Abandon();

    value = Session["value"];

    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

View code

```
@Html.ActionLink("Logout","Logout")
```

Comment: Thanks for reply sir,it is not working,it is passing session id after logout also.

Comment: Maybe you are setting the session id variable before removing it from the session? Ideally need some more code where you are displaying it. Instead of "return View();" do "return RedirectToAction("Index");" where Index is a another valid Action in the controller. Do you get the same issue when trying to retrieve the session id from the other action?

Comment: public ActionResult Logout()
        {

            string em = "";
            em = (string)Session["value"];
            if (em != null)
            {
                Session.Remove("value");
                Session.Remove("value1");
                Session["value"] = "";
                Session["value1"] = "";

            }  

            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

Comment: Tha code checks for the value not being null, but you never set it to null.

Comment: i am using null also but it is not working,Again i used quates.

Comment: Please see my above edit. Let me know how you get on!